# Datadog APM: Search tags in multiple spans of the same trace

Tags: datadog

I have a Datadog APM trace from my Rails monolith that looks a bit like this:

Sidekiq job

- Rails cache: GET
- Rails cache: GET

  - cache miss results in an HTTP request to another service (using the Faraday HTTP client), and it errors out

Each line is a separate span. I would like to search for the failed HTTP requests and then look up certain tags from the corresponding Sidekiq span, but I don't see a way to do so? I am approaching this by querying Datadog APM for something like

```
service:my_service resource_name:POST @peer.hostname=my.other.service.host @http.path_group:/route status:error
```

but that, predictably, gives me back the Faraday traces, and if I open any of them I can visually inspect them and see their Sidekiq parent, but I can't programatically pull tags from that parents span into my Datadog facets or columns.